# Rubber material (Adidas Boost alike)

Tags: materials, shaders, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to figure out a way to recreate this polyurethane-particles like effect, as is in Adidas Boost soles (see image), either via procedural shaders or though geometry nodes.. Anyone has done something like that before?

[image]